# Assign an integer for each group in a column

Tags: r, grouping

I have a data set that is organized like this

```
Date:
4/2/2018
5/6/2018
4/2/2018
7/1/2018
7/1/2018
5/6/2018
```

I would like it to be organized like this:

```
Date:                ID:
4/2/2018             1 
5/6/2018             2
4/2/2018             1
7/1/2018             3
7/1/2018             3
5/6/2018             2
```

Does anyone know how to do this? My data is organized in a data table with date as one of the columns and I need to create a new column called id.

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: R sorry, thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO. What code have you attempted so far? are you open to using other packages or is a data.table solution preferred?

Comment: I have attempted to use the dplyr package. Today is my first day in R, so I am unfamiliar with how to do things. A data table solution is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `rleid` from `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
dt[order(Date),ID:=rleid(Date)]
```

**Result:**

```
       Date ID
1: 4/2/2018  1
2: 5/6/2018  2
3: 4/2/2018  1
4: 7/1/2018  3
5: 7/1/2018  3
6: 5/6/2018  2
```

**Data:**

```
dt <- read.table(text = "Date
4/2/2018
                 5/6/2018
                 4/2/2018
                 7/1/2018
                 7/1/2018
                 5/6/2018", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

setDT(dt)
```

Comment: having problems with this as the date field is a string, any thoughts?

Comment: @SavannahMorrisseyMartin Are you saying it's a string in your data or in my answer? What is the desired format for `Date`?

Comment: the date variable in my table is a string. I appreciate your help!

Comment: @SavannahMorrisseyMartin Format doesn't matter for this answer. It should work whether your `Date` is a string or factor or Date format. Nonetheless, I've changed the format of the sample `Date` from a factor to a string.

Comment: Awesome works thanks!